# Java and asp.net, send array of string via webservers

Tags: c#, java, arrays, string, wsdl

I have problem with sedn list of string through asp.Net webservis. I created this method:

```
public string[] pobierzzarray()
       {
         List<string> list = new List<string>();
           if (Session["uzytkownicy"] != null)
               list = (List<string>)Session["uzytkownicy"];
          string[] s = new string[list.Count];
          for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ ) {

              s[i] = list.ElementAt(i);

          }
```

But when he is called throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. --->System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String []' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List `1 [System.String]'

What I should do to send this array.

```
           return s;
       }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I try to build a Java client using the WSDL to generate the method. First, the client has created a C # and works fine, but now I'm trying to build the same client in Java. And this mrthot return empty array.

Comment: You may be trying to build a Java client, but all the code you show is C#. Also, the exception is pretty self-explanatory but see @ArnoldZokas answer below.

Comment: @Perception I think that the problem is in the webserver, as pointed previously, this method return only a list of strings. Java Generated ArrayofString class with the method getString, but only returns an empty array.

Comment: Here in Java class return 0 pobierzzarray().getString().size() but in C# is number greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your session (`Session["uzytkownicy"]`) is storing string array, not a string list, so the cast is failing.

Try this:

```
public string[] pobierzzarray()
{
    List<string> list;

    if (Session["uzytkownicy"] != null)
        list = new List<string>(Session["uzytkownicy"] as string[]);

    // ... the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Not work in line 'list = new List<string>(Session["uzytkownicy"] as string[]);' is problem, _Value can not be zero. Parameter name: collection_ even though I added to the list of object